# How to normalize values in a particular field in unix?

Tags: bash, awk

I have some tab separated data like this

```
a       5
b       4
c       3
d       2
e       1
```

I want to normalize values in the second column wrt the max value(max value is the value in the first row), basically I am expecting some thing like this

```
a       1
b       0.8
c       0.6
d       0.4
e       0.2
```

I can get the max values by doing(because data is sorted by the values in the second column)

> ```
> max=`cat values | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
> ```

However, I can't figure out the rest of the command. Could somebody please help me with this?

Comment: You don't need `cat` in there.  Do you know that the maximum will always be the first value?  You really don't need `head` if you use `awk`.  Will the data always be in two columns only?  How many lines are you dealing with?  Hundreds, thousands, millions, more?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes the max is in the first value because they are reverse sorted. And there are thousand of values.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1 {max = $2}   { $2 /= max; print }'
```

Since the maximum is in the first row, simply capture that value.  Then divide column 2 by that value in each row and print the result.

Also, given that the maximum is the first value, there's no need to worry about the file size.  If the maximum could appear anywhere in the file, then you might have needed to read the whole file into memory, in which case large files would be a problem.